# Removing "." from Spark DataFrame column names

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How do I remove the "." from a Spark DataFrame column name?

The `DataFrame.select(F.col().alias())` method to rename column names that have a "." in them throws an error.

The following code is reproducible.

```
# import Spark libraries, configuration, Contexts, and types.
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
#############
# Start Spark.
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test").getOrCreate()

testdf = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, "Julie", "CEO"),
    (2, "Janice", "CFO"),
    (3, "Jake", "CTO")],
    ["ID", "First Name", "Title Initial."])

# this works just fine.
testdf.select(F.col('First Name').alias('first_name')).show(3)

# This throws an error. 
testdf.select(F.col('Title Initial.').alias('title')).show(3)
```

Error:

```
AnalysisException: u'syntax error in attribute name: Title Initial.;'
```

What is an alternative method to change DataFrame column names that have a "." in them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surround the column name with `` ` ``

```
testdf.select(F.col('`Title Initial.`').alias('title')).show(3)
```

Comment: Awesome!  And I was using a dictionary called `colname_map` to rename all of the columns in my actual DataFrame, the following worked well `testdf = testdf.select([F.col(c).alias(colname_map.get(c, c)) for c in ["\`"+x+"\`" for x in df.columns]])`  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Today I met the same problem in PySpark 3.3.1 with Python 3.9.16, add '`' at the beginning and the end of the column can works.

```
...
col_name = 'No.'
df = df.withColumn(col_name, df[col_name].cast('bigint'))
```

will raise a error: `AnalysisException: syntax error in attribute name: No.`

After add '`', it works:

```
df = df.withColumn(col_name, df["`"+col_name+"`"].cast('bigint'))
```

Comment: @RyanXu The edit to change from a thanks to manojlds, is this still just a rehash of manojlds's solution?

Comment: this works wonders, when dynamically selecting the column names and/or renaming them